# Pass jQuery noConflict() to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have a common JS file for my site that uses a lot of jQuery. A form that I'm trying to implement uses prototype.js, so there is a conflict, and I would prefer not to change the namespace in my common JS file.

Is it possible to load the form via AJAX and somehow release the "$" so that the form scripts can load properly?

What I mean is:

... the HTML page includes a DIV where the form should load:

```
<div id="form-container"></div>
<script src="myScripts.js"></script>
```

... and myScripts.js file would include this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "form-code.html",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $.noConflict();
    },
    dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(html){
    $("#form-container").html(html);
});
```

... and form-code.html would include:

```
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<form>
    <!-- form code here -->
</form>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have to change in the common js file. You cannot use that in an ajax query. The whole point of using noConflict is that $ is not used by the other library when it is in use by one. And declaring that in an ajax calls betray that intention because till then prototype and jQuery declare $ in their own way.